# How does C# handle calling an interface method on a struct?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, interface, cil

Consider:

```
interface I { void M(); }
struct S: I { public void M() {} }
// in Main:
S s;
I i = s;
s.M();
i.M();
```

And the IL for Main:

```
.maxstack 1
.entrypoint
.locals init (
    [0] valuetype S s,
    [1] class I i
)

IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldloc.0
IL_0002: box S
IL_0007: stloc.1
IL_0008: ldloca.s s
IL_000a: call instance void S::M()
IL_000f: nop
IL_0010: ldloc.1
IL_0011: callvirt instance void I::M()
IL_0016: nop
IL_0017: ret
```

First (`IL_000a`), `S::M()` is called with a value type for `this`. Next (`IL_0011`), it's called with a reference (boxed) type.

**How does this work?**

I can think of three ways:

1. Two versions of `I::M` are compiled, for value/ref type. In the vtable, it stores the one for ref type, but statically dispatched calls use the one for value types. *This is ugly and unlikely, but possible.*
2. In the vtable, it stores a "wrapper" method that unboxes `this`, then calls the actual method. *This sounds inefficient because all the method's arguments would have to be copied through two calls.*
3. There's special logic that checks for this in `callvirt`. *Even more inefficient: all `callvirt`s incur a (slight) penalty.*

Comment: Note `IL_0002: box S`. The struct is boxed to allow the call. Although there is a way around that with generics.

Comment: @Joey that's for `I i = s;`; the first call uses the value type `ldloca.s s`

Comment: It is convoluted and looking at the IL does not help at all.  A basic understanding of the way dispatch stubs in the CLR are used is required.  Vance Morrison of the CLR team explains it fairly well in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2006/03/13/digging-into-interface-calls-in-the-net-framework-stub-based-dispatch/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that in the method itself, the value of the `struct` is always accessed *through a pointer*. That means that method does not operate as if the `struct` was passed as a normal parameter, it's more like a `ref` parameter. It also means that the method does not know whether it's operating on boxed value or not.

The long answer:

First, if I compile your code, then `s.M();` does not generate any code. The JIT compiler is smart enough to inline the method and inlining an empty method results in no code. So, what I did is to apply `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` on `S.M` to avoid this.

Now, here is the native code your method generates (omitting function prolog and epilog):

```
// initialize s in register AX
xor         eax,eax  
// move s from register AX to stack (SP+28h)
mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],rax  
// load pointer to MethodTable for S to register CX
mov         rcx,7FFDB00C5B08h  
// allocate memory for i on heap
call        JIT_TrialAllocSFastMP_InlineGetThread (07FFE0F824C10h)  
// copy contents of s from stack to register C
movsx       rcx,byte ptr [rsp+28h]  
// copy from register CX to heap
mov         byte ptr [rax+8],cl  
// copy pointer to i from register AX to register SI
mov         rsi,rax  
// load address to c on stack to register CX
lea         rcx,[rsp+28h]  
// call S::M
call        00007FFDB01D00C8  
// copy pointer to i from register SI to register CX
mov         rcx,rsi  
// move address of stub for I::M to register 11
mov         r11,7FFDB00D0020h  
// ???
cmp         dword ptr [rcx],ecx  
// call stub for I::M
call        qword ptr [r11]
```

In both cases, the `call` ends up calling the same code (which is just a single `ret` instruction). The first time, the CX register points to the stack-allocated `s` (SP+28h in the above code), the second time to the heap-allocated `i` (AX+8 just after the call to the heap allocation function).

Comment: So `this` is always a pointer; in a ref type method, it points to the type information field (immediately before the first field), and in a value type it points directly to the first field, which _may be an internal pointer to a boxed value_.